# Score counter for rock paper scissor game javascript

Tags: javascript

i have finished my rock paper scissor game, and i am now working on adding a score to it. The problem i have is that i can't get the program to increment the score, but instead it resets every round. 
I have tried making the two variables, and then adding +1 in my function whenever one of them wins but i can't get it to save.

```js
var userscore = 0;
var computerscore = 0;

function computerdecision() {
  var Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  switch (Number) {
    case 0:
      return "rock";
    case 1:
      return "scissor";
    case 2:
      return "paper";
  }
}

function declareWinner(userweapon, computerweapon) {
  if (userweapon === computerweapon) {
    console.log("Tiebreak");
  } else if (userweapon === "rock" && computerweapon === "scissor" ||
    userweapon === "paper" && computerweapon === "rock" || userweapon === "scissor" && computerweapon ===
    "paper") {
    console.log("User won");
    userscore++;
  } else {
    console.log("Computer won");
    computerscore++;
  }
}

var userweapon = "rock"
var computerweapon = computerdecision();

console.log('Your weapon is: ' + userweapon);
console.log("Computer's weapon is: " + computerweapon);

declareWinner(userweapon, computerweapon);

console.log("User: " + userscore)
console.log("computer: " + computerscore)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: @adiga finally  i  figured out how to do it lol . Thanks!

Comment: post your result then as an answer

Comment: How do you go to the next round?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to play another round the user need to refresh the page (as @EmielZuurbier comment), so unless you use some sort of data saving - all records will lost.

A quick fix will be to make a button that will call the function again. But this won't save records after exit / refresh. And i guess this is not what you are searching...

Anyway, i edit and rewrite your code to make it playable + added some local storage score board. I leave you the fun part to change the onclick events and to style it as you want.

```js
var userscore = localStorage.getItem('userScore');
document.querySelector("#userScore").textContent = userscore;
var computerscore = localStorage.getItem('computerScore');
document.querySelector("#computerScore").textContent = computerscore;

function computerdecision() {
  var Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  switch (Number) {
    case 0:
      return "rock";
    case 1:
      return "scissor";
    case 2:
      return "paper";
  }
}

function declareWinner() {
  var computerweapon = computerdecision();
  var userweapon = document.querySelector('input[name="weapon"]:checked').value;
  if (userweapon === computerweapon) {
    document.querySelector("#gameResult").textContent = " Tiebreak ";
  } 
  else if (userweapon === "rock" && computerweapon === "scissor" || userweapon === "paper" && computerweapon === "rock" || userweapon === "scissor" && computerweapon === "paper") {
    document.querySelector("#gameResult").textContent = " User won ";
    userscore++;
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#gameResult").textContent = " Computer won ";
    computerscore++;
  }
document.querySelector("#userWeapon").textContent = " User weapon was: " + userweapon;
document.querySelector("#computerWeapon").textContent = " Computer's weapon was: " + computerweapon;

document.querySelector("#userScore").textContent = userscore;
localStorage.setItem('userScore', userscore);
document.querySelector("#computerScore").textContent = computerscore;
localStorage.setItem('computerScore', computerscore);
}
```

```html
<label for="rock"><input type="radio" name="weapon" id="rock" value="rock" checked />Rock</label>
<label for="paper"><input type="radio"name="weapon" id="paper" value="paper" />Paper</label>
<label for="scissor"><input type="radio"name="weapon" id="scissor" value="scissor" />Scissor</label>

<button onclick="declareWinner();">Play</button>
<div> 
Game Result: <span id="gameResult"></span>
<br />
Computer: <mark id="computerScore"></mark>
<br />
Computer Weapon: <span id="computerWeapon"></span>
<br />
User: <mark id="userScore"></mark>
<br />
User Weapon: <span id="userWeapon"></span>
</div>
<hr />
<button onclick="localStorage.clear();">clear saved records</button>
```

Hope it helps! If you have more questions leave a comment.

---

P.S - The score board won't work here on stack's since it restricted, so you should copy-paste and run it on your machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, makes great sense :-)